# Como não ser obrigado a informar a extensão do arquivo em import NodeJS

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, módulo-ecmascript

Estou utilizando `"type": "module"` em meu `package.json` para utilizar ECMAScript Modules na minha aplicação.

Porém notei que, toda vez que vou importar um arquivo, preciso informar a extensão do arquivo senão ele não acha o módulo.

O erro erro retornado é: `Cannot find module "...\Users" imported from "...\index.js" Did you mean to import ../Users.js?`

Arquivo `index.js`:

```
import Users from './Users.js' // from './Users' não funciona

console.log(Users)
```

Arquivo `users.js`:

```
const Users = {
    id_user: 1,
    name: "Teste"
}

export default Users
```

Seria possível contornar isso para fazer como no ReactJS, por exemplo?

Onde não é preciso informar a extensão ou o nome do arquivo caso seja o arquivo `index.js` de uma pasta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: Isso não é possível.

O Node.js implementou o ECMAScript Modules tal como previsto na especificação da linguagem, que exige tais terminações. Ao contrário do `require` que, pelos termos do CommonJS, torna a extensão opcional, no ESM elas são obrigatórias.

Para saber mais, consulte a [documentação](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/esm.html#mandatory-file-extensions).

---

Vale ressaltar que, no React, por exemplo, isto funcionaria:

```
import UserContext from './context/user';
```

Porque o código fonte JavaScript é pré-processado por um *bundler* como o Webpack. Originalmente a implementação dos ECMAScript Modules, embora sintaticamente semelhante, não era totalmente fidedigna.

Novas implementações, tais como o Node.js, que implementou ESM recentemente, seguem o padrão da linguagem.